# TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.categories.map...')

Tags: react-native

What is the ERROR in this map??
the back-end works ,,but i have no clue what i am doing here,but any help would
be appreciated

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categories:[],
    }}

componentDidMount = async()=>{
 try{
   let data = await fetch("http://192.168.6.107:8080/cetegories");
   let res = await data.json();
   console.log("data",res);
   this.setState({
     categories:res
   })
 }
 catch(err){
   console.log(err)

 }
}
```

This is the map in render:

```
 <View >
          {this.state.categories.map((item ,key)=>(
          <View key={key}>
           <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          </View> ))
          }
        </View>
```

console.log("data",res) in the server;

```
data Object {
[front] [23:22:26]   "results": Array [
[front] [23:22:26]     Object {
[front] [23:22:26]       "cate_id": 1,
[front] [23:22:26]       "name": "vehicles",
[front] [23:22:26]     },
[front] [23:22:26]     Object {
[front] [23:22:26]       "cate_id": 2,
[front] [23:22:26]       "name": "home",
[front] [23:22:26]     },
[front] [23:22:26]     Object {
[front] [23:22:26]       "cate_id": 3,
[front] [23:22:26]       "name": "electronics",
[front] [23:22:26]     },
[front] [23:22:26]   ],
[front] [23:22:26]   "success": true,
[front] [23:22:26] }
```

Comment: Try to console.log(this.state.categories) in the beginning of render().

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do a map in an object instead of an array at the time of a correct response from your api your state categories looks like this

```
categories = { 
  results: [ ...data ]
}
```

You could iterate the results inside your categories(but for this you will have to validate that you actually have a results property inside your categories).

```
    <View >
      {this.state.categories.results.map((item ,key)=>(
      <View key={key}>
       <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      </View> ))
      }
    </View>
```

or the easier assign the results to categories:

```
this.setState({
     categories:res.results
   })
```

Comment: I'm glad, Please don't forget to accept the answer so more people can benefit from it.